# python function to set accuracy of float

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal, rounding, floating-accuracy

I would like to make a function:

```
def accuracy(number, index):
```

For example

- `accuracy(2.5e-10, -5)` would return 0.
- `accuracy(49, 2)` would return 0.
- `accuracy(50, 2)` would return 100.

  So basically it would round to the closest 10 power of the index `index`
  How would you do that?

Comment: ... by using `round()`? What is the problem with your code, do you get an error or incorrect results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def accuracy(n, i):
    return round(float(n) / 10**i) * 10**i
```

Comment: `round(float(n), -i)` is simpler.