# redefine behaviour of float

Tags: python, operator-overloading

I have a function `accuracy(n)` which sets accuracy for float number n. Is it possible to overload somekind of operator of type float so that:

```
f = 1.5
x = f
```

would be automatically implemented (in the background) as:

```
x = accuracy(f)
```

Thanks a lot

**Edit** Is it possible to overload `__eq__` of `float`?

Comment: You cannot override assignment.

Comment: Duplicate of [python function to set accuracy of float](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18219400/python-function-to-set-accuracy-of-float)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any overloading you can do so that those exact lines will behave the way you described, but you can get something similar:

```
class Foo(object):
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = accuracy(value)

foo = Foo()

f = 1.5
foo.x = f     # set foo._x to accuracy(f)
print(foo.x)  # prints foo._x
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Something else: Is it possible to overload `__eq__` for `float`?

Comment: @gen You should probably ask that as a separate question, it won't get much attention as an edit on an old post.  It is possible to make a subclass of `float` with its own `__eq__` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

No. But you can create a class that defines `__float__()` so that the new value is used when the object is used in a float context.

Comment: Thanks, something else: Is it possible to overload `__eq__` for `float`?

Comment: You cannot patch classes written in C.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can write a class and define a `__setattr__` method so that your function is called to preprocess data assigned to member attributes. Something like:

```
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
   if isinstance(value, float):
      self.__dict__[name] = accuracy(value)
   else:
      self.__dict__[name] = value
```

Comment: Thank you, Something else: Is it possible to overload `__eq__` for `float`?